# How to add values one by one in a new column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column with acceleration values, and I’m trying to integrate them in a new column.
Here’s what I want as output :

```
  A B
0 a b-a
1 b c-b
2 c d-c
3 d …-d
…
```

I’m currently doing like that

```
l=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
   l.append(df.values[i+1][0]-df.values[i][0])
df[1]=l
```

That’s very slow to process.
I have over a million lines, and this in 20 different csv files. Is there a way to do it faster ?

Comment: I'm sure that's possible with vectorized operations. Can't say anything else given the information you provided.

Comment: @timgeb dont really know what else to add, i think my question is clear, and I couldn’t find any answer or help anywhere

Comment: Your question has no sample data, no code, no actual output and no desired output. It could be much, much clearer.

Comment: See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/3620003).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,2,1,10]})
df['B'] = -df['A'].diff(-1)
```

output:

```
    A    B
0   0  2.0
1   2 -1.0
2   1  9.0
3  10  NaN
```

Comment: note that `df['A'].diff().shift(1)` also works but is slightly less efficient